# Query to get pre and post values within 2% of each other?

Tags: mysql

I have data for a body fat pretest and a posttest.  If the post test value is larger than the pre test, it can only be 2% larger or I don't want it in the results.  The post test value can be any amount lower than the pre test.

This query only works when both values are within 2% of each other.  The missing piece is when the post test is lower than the pre test.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
SELECT LPAD( `studid` , 7, '0' ) AS studid, 
       bodpoints, 
       STR_TO_DATE(TestDate, '%m/%d/%Y') AS testd 
FROM bodpod, points 
WHERE ABS((post - pre) / pre) <= '0.02' 
AND ID2 = 'fall' 
AND studid != '' 
GROUP BY studid 
HAVING COUNT( DISTINCT ID1 ) >=1 AND YEAR( testd ) = '2013'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `ABS((post - pre) / pre) <= '0.02'` to `((post - pre) / pre) <= 0.02` you should get the answer you need.

By removing the `ABS` it allows us to check for changes in either direction. By checking for a change of less than 0.02 we're making sure the change is not more than 2% up (if the change was down we'll get a negative, so that'll still pass the check.)

**EDIT** Sorry, I think I had the answer back-to-front!